# How can i set up dynamic database size using HTML5 Web SQL Database?

Tags: android, html, cordova, local-storage, offlineapps

I am working on Android Application using HTML5. I am using HTML5 Web SQL database for local data storage. I want this database to grow dynamically as it requires to be like that. 
I am using Phonegap as development framework to build this android application.

Comment: In what way is it not growing at the moment?  Are you hitting some hard limit?

Comment: No, its not growing. I don't want to set size in the openDatabase call as the table which are going to be created are in dynamic size.

Comment: So you're creating a database, then filling it up, and then it's refusing to add any more data?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes. Its not giving error. But i want that size to be dynamic. Can i set dynamic size for database using openDatabse call ?

Comment: The size will be dynamic, up to whatever limit is imposed by the browser/file system.  The size in the openDatabase is just advisory AFAIK.